# dataproc cluster update (resize) command not completing

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

We have a dataproc cluster we dynamically resize for large jobs. I submitted a cluster resize request to reduce our cluster to its original size (1m,2workers) from 10-workers, 3-preemptive workers but this still hasn't completed an hour later.

Is this normal? is there a way to re-issue the request? at the moment I get cluster update in progress style messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you downscale Dataproc 1.2+ cluster using [Graceful Decommissioning](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/scaling-clusters#graceful_decommissioning) this is expected that it could take a long time if there are running jobs on cluster - downscale operation will wait until YARN containers will finish on decommissioned nodes.

Also, if you are intensively using HDFS, nodes decommissioning could take a long time for data to be replicated to prevent data loss.

You can not issue another resize operation until current operation is finished.